# Is there a script to select what row to run a macro in based on matching cell values from 2 sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need help getting my macro to transfer data into a specific row in another sheet based on the value in the first column of that sheet.

I have two different Sheets set up in a Google Workbook. One sheet is very large and complex so difficult to enter information into (Sheet 2). I have set-up the second sheet to show just the information that needs to be entered so it is easy to complete (Sheet 1). I've recorded a macro to move the data from the entry sheet to the end sheet (Basically just a copy/paste) at the click of a button.

What I need help with is getting it to copy the data to the correct row in that sheet.

The quick entry sheet (Sheet 1) has a spot to enter the date that the information is being added for. This date will then correspond to a date in the larger file (Sheet 2). This is the row that the data needs to be moved to (done through the macro). Is there a script that will match the date from Sheet 1 with the row corresponding to that date in Sheet 2 to tell the macro what row to run the data copy/paste in?

Sheet 1:
[Sheet 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t_vI-9CxM4nKtO9Ame_SsPD8ihr-iOeF/view?usp=sharing)

Sheet 2:
[Sheet 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wg5C1EPHt6hj-UkY1l37KMzfDISqZ4tg/view?usp=sharing)

Let me know if you have any questions or if I need to send the photos differently.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What code have you tried so far? If you have written any yet then try reading [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

Answer (score 0):

## Copy from any range to any other range in same spreadsheet

Here's a custom dialog for selecting from and to ranges and performing a range to range copy.

There's a lot of ways to do this. I have a simple templated html that I use for whipping these kind of things out fairly quickly.  This took me the length of ButterFly Effect 2 that I listened to in the background.  But I don't type as quickly as I used to.

I started by doing a macro and this is the macro script:

```
function CopyRangeFromSheetToSheet() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-2, 0, 1, 7).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('InvData'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(3, 5).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('form response'), true);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('InvData'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-2, -5, 1, 7).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'form response\'!A9:G9').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
}
```

But I believe you wanted to specify from and to ranges so I decided to use a custom modeless dialog that allows one to select from and to ranges by select the sheet and range and pressing a button for the from and the two and when you have both ranges captured you press the copy button and walla it copies and removes the dialog.  It takes a few files and they're all below:

example1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('res1') ?>
    <?!= include('css1') ?>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="control">
     <br />FROM: <input type="text" id="fromTxt" placeholder="Select From Range" /><input type="button" value="Select From" onClick="selectFrom();" />
     <br />TO: <input type="text" id="toTxt" placeholder="Select To Range" /><input type="button" value="Select To" onClick="selectTo();" />
     <br /><input type="button" value="Copy" onClick="runCopy();" />
   </div>

   <?!= include('script1') ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

res1.html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

script1.html:

```
<script>
  $(function(){

  });
  function selectFrom() {
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(rgstr){
      $('#fromTxt').val(rgstr);
    })
    .selectFrom();
  }
  function selectTo() {
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(rgstr){
      $('#toTxt').val(rgstr);
    })
    .selectTo();
  }
  function runCopy() {
    var from=$('#fromTxt').val();
    var to=$('#toTxt').val();
    var cObj={from:from,to:to};
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(s){
      google.script.host.close();
    })
    .performCopy(cObj);
  }
  console.log('My Code');
</script>
```

css1.html:

```
<style>
body {background-color:#ffffff;}
input{padding:2px;margin:2px;}
</style>
```

exampl1.gs

```
function selectFrom() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getActiveRange();
  var rgstr=Utilities.formatString('\'%s\'!%s',sh.getName(),rg.getA1Notation());
  return rgstr;
}

function selectTo() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getActiveRange();
  var rgstr=Utilities.formatString('\'%s\'!%s',sh.getName(),rg.getA1Notation());
  return rgstr;
}

function performCopy(cObj) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var frg=ss.getRange(cObj.from);
  var trg=ss.getRange(cObj.to);
  frg.copyTo(trg);
  return 'done';
}
function showExample1Dialog(){
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('example1').evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Example1");
}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

- [Spreadsheet Doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Class UI](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)